# Holding your objects in Matlab

Tags: matlab, object, collections

I would like to store a collection of objects in an associative array with a key object pair. The goal is to to be able to later on lookup the object with the key.

I would expect I should be able to use the containers.map built-in class for that. I have written the following example code to illustrate what I mean:

```
classdef clsMyClass < handle
   properties 
      dblMyProperty1
   end 
   methods
      function self = clsMyClass(dblValue)
        if nargin > 0
          for intCounter = numel(dblValue):-1:1
              self(intCounter).dblMyProperty1 = dblValue(intCounter);
          end                
        end
      end      
   end
end 

classdef clsMyClassCollection < handle
   properties 
      contMyCollection
   end 
   methods
      function self = clsMyClassCollection(strValues,strKeys)
        if nargin > 0
          self.contMyCollection= containers.Map(strKeys, clsMyClass(strValues));
        end
      end      
   end
end 

for i=10:-1:1 ; vecKeys{i} = ['A' num2str(i)];end;
objMyClassCollection = clsMyClassCollection ([0:10:90],vecKeys);
```

This will result in the following error:

```
??? Error using ==> containers.Map
The values must be a cell array when the keys are a cell array.
```

It would great if I could get some assistance in fixing this error and if you can tell me if this is the best way of implementing key object collections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
self.contMyCollection= containers.Map(strKeys, num2cell( clsMyClass(strValues)) );
```

Comment: @Ruut `containers.Map` seesm like the right choice for your specifications. Do you understand the cause of error and why this change fixes it?